# mySQL: Joining 2 tables with values from varchar

Tags: mysql

Hi I need help trying to figure out how to join two tables and retrieve values from a varchar as foreign keys. 
The table is similar to the table below.

### Table_Contractor

**TraderID**- -**Name**- -**Skill_ID**

1  - - - - - - - Joe - - - 1,2,3,4

2 - - - - - - - Bob - - - 1,3

3 - - - - - - --Tom - - - 4,3,1

---

### Table_Trade

**Skill_ID**- -**Skill_Title**

1- - - - - - - Plumber

2- - - - - - -Bricklayer

3- - - - - - -Electrician

4- - - - - - -Plasterer

---

I would like to be able to SELECT the TraderId and Name and display the name of the Skill instead of the Skill_ID

---

**TraderID**- -**Name**- -**Skills**

1  - - - - - - - Joe - - - Plumber, Bricklayer, Electrician, Plasterer

2 - - - - - - - Bob - - - Plumber, Electrician

3 - - - - - - --Tom - - - Plasterer, Electrician, Plumber

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the structure of your tables, I would strongly suggest the following tables:

- contractor: id, name
- contractor_skill: contractor_id, skill_id
- skill: id, title

You can get the result you want easily then:

```
   SELECT c.id, c.name, GROUP_CONCAT(s.title) skills
     FROM contractor c
LEFT JOIN contractor_skill cs
       ON cs.contractor_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN skill s
       ON s.id = c.skill_id
```

Using your current structure, to join the tables you would need to extract each skill_id from the csv list for each contractor and join it to the relevant skill.. MySQL isn't built for this. Also operations such as adding, removing or ordering the skills of a contractor become really messy.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I was thinking it might be something like that but I wasn't sure what way to go about it. Thank for the info